# How to get a properly typed List from a ReflectionDBObject

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a model classes like

```
public class MyClass extends ReflectionDBObject {
    private List<NiceAttribute> attributes;    
    ...
}

public class NiceAttribute extends ReflectionDBObject {
    ...
}
```

I create it in a typesafe way, like

```
List<NiceAttribute> attrs = new ArrayList<NiceAttribute>();
attrs.add(new NiceAttribute());
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.setAttributes(attrs);
```

then save it to mongo, and retrieve with a code like

```
DBCollection col = ...;
col.setObjectClass(MyClass.class)
MyClass foundObject = (MyClass)col.findOne();
```

But the problem is that `foundObject`'s `attributes` becomes a list of `BasicDBObject`. Looks like a driver can not (or does not want to) detect a list items type. Is this a driver limitation, or I missed something? What would be an elegant workaround for the problem?

BTW, I know about Morphia etc. Maybe it solves the problem. But my project is tiny, and I don't want to complicate things having one more layer of abstraction.

Answer (score 4):

Well, there is a solution, but you're not gonna like it. Basically you can specify the corresponding class for an internal path within your object. Here's what I did, and it works:

```
public class Release extends ReflectionDBObject {

    //other fields omitted    

    private List<ReleaseDetailsByTerritory> releaseDetailsByTerritory = new ArrayList<ReleaseDetailsByTerritory>();

}

public class ReleaseDetailsByTerritory extends ReflectionDBObject { //...}
```

Now, if I simply do this:

```
    releaseColl.setObjectClass(Release.class);
    releaseColl.setInternalClass("ReleaseDetailsByTerritory.0", ReleaseDetailsByTerritory.class);
    Release r = (Release) releaseColl.findOne();
    //the internal list will contain ReleaseDetailsByTerritory type objects (not DBObjects)
    System.out.println(r.getReleaseDetailsByTerritory().get(0).getClass().getName());
```

The crappy thing here is that you can't (or at least I haven't found how) to specify the mapping class for ALL the elements of an embedded array. You CANNOT do something like:

```
releaseColl.setInternalClass("ReleaseDetailsByTerritory", ReleaseDetailsByTerritory.class);
```

or

```
releaseColl.setInternalClass("ReleaseDetailsByTerritory.*", ReleaseDetailsByTerritory.class);
```

You have instead to specify the mapping class of any possible element of the embedded array:

```
releaseColl.setInternalClass("ReleaseDetailsByTerritory.0", ReleaseDetailsByTerritory.class);
releaseColl.setInternalClass("ReleaseDetailsByTerritory.1", ReleaseDetailsByTerritory.class);
releaseColl.setInternalClass("ReleaseDetailsByTerritory.2", ReleaseDetailsByTerritory.class);
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use Morphia. It adds support for POJOs and embedded objects (and collections). It doesn't have any of the limitations the driver does about requiring your classes to look like a `Map<String, Object>`.

Comment: Morphia is about 10-15x slower than the driver. You're better off writing your own code to do the mapping.

Comment: We have performance tests in morphia which shows this to not be true. If you have some tests which show this performance issue it would be good if you could share them.

Comment: I've actually done very basic tests, where I write the same entry about 10-20k times, using driver, then Spring Mongo Db then Morphia. Driver is fastest, Spring Mongo is about 2x slower and morphia is about 7-10x slower. Even on a mongo with real collection sharding (on multiple machines) it's still slower. You can easily test this.

Comment: As I said, there are unit tests in morphia which don't show this. Can you please provide the tests you are using?

Comment: Well, the fact that Morphia has tests which result that Moprphia is fastest might be a bit biased. Just try to save something like 100k elements, each having something like 2 numerical attributes, one string one (which should habe like a 10-20k string), and maybe an embedded array of similar entities with 10-20 elements.

Comment: The tests are not meant to compare to other frameworks but just to make sure that morphia is not more that some % worse than the core driver. They are there to ensure that performance regressions are not introduced into the code. They may need to be improved and that is why I was asking for code to see what you did, and how you found your numbers, since they were not seen in the tests in morphia.

Comment: Well, just make some BasicDBObject (or ReflectionDBObject like) instancecs, persist them with driver and then persist similar Morphia beans with the same data, see how long each take to happen. I've done a bunch of these tests, and the driver was always waaay faster. Especially (but not limited to) when you have many embedded objects, as the driver just creates DBObjects for them (which are really linkedMaps) while Morphia uses a ton of reflection to create Morphia instances.